# How do I defeat the Automaton?

Tags: bravely-default-demo

I can't seem to kill it.

I've gotten to a point where the boss'll just start healing at 1000 hp for about a few turns.  This gets horrible because I run dry on MP just trying to nuke it.

Help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When I took on the Automaton I had 2 Valkyries as my main heavy hitters. Specifically, they each had the best spear I could equip on them and the Knight's `Two-Hand` support skill. This doubles the damage for any weapon held with both hands. I also had a White Mage and I think a Ninja.

When the battle started I defaulted for a few turns to build BP (so I could keep jumping without going into negative BP). When I was ready, I had my two Valkyries jump. They landed in the next round and did 1200-1500 damage to the boss. All I had to do was keep hitting it and keep healing and I got through with no problems. Other characters attacked, supported and healed as needed.

Comment: The Valkyrie passive that increases BP cost and damage also works well alongside the Two-Hand ability and Jump. I was fortunate enough to get a critical doing that which took off like 4K or something nuts.